# Can't fully look around in cameraview - walk mode

Tags: camera

When using walk mode in camera view i want to be able to look around inside my model. But when I use my mouse I get stuck being able to only "look up" in x direction (>180 degrees).I can rotate in z direction. But I can't look down in x direction, i.e. decrease rotation x.[image: I get stuck in this position, not able to look towards the origin]

Edit: I've  uploaded my blend file here[image]

Comment: Maybe try setting your camera y-rotation to 0 instead of 180° ? Y-rotation corresponds to roll, the equivalent to tilting your head left/right. For most cases, you don't want to change y-rotation.

Comment: Setting the y-rotation to 0 results in the same problem. As soon as i look around with x-rotation, i can't look back to the origin

Comment: Maybe remove your keyframes ? Otherwise upload your file with https://blend-exchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but the removing the keyframes doesn't help either. I added my file to the post. However I have the same problem when starting a clean file, so maybe there's just an issue with (my) blender itself

Comment: Last idea, try reset rotation with Alt+R.